# Force stop when run app in moblie

Tags: android, listview, android-developer-api

I try to work with list view and on click open another activity but when I run the app on mobile it force stop. Below is my code for Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
String TopicList[]={"jan","Feb"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.topic);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TopicList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position==0){

        Intent myInternt= new Intent(view.getContext(),Vlookup.class);
        startActivityForResult(myInternt,0);

    }
    if (position==1){

        Intent myInternt= new Intent(view.getContext(),Hlookup.class);
        startActivityForResult(myInternt,1);
    }
}
  }
```

> Blockquote

Below my Maindest.xml file

`enter code here

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Vlookup" />
    <activity android:name=".Hlookup"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: make sure Vlookup.class and Hlookup.class are declared in manifest.

Comment: post your `logcat`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line from the code:-

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

by:-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TopicList);
```

you are not adding list to adapter therefore it crashes,
And also check the manifest that the activity is added to it.

Comment: Done but same issue                                                     
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TopicList);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined MainActivity, Vlookup and Hlookup in your manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Vlookup"/>
    <activity android:name=".Hlookup"/>
```

and replace

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

by

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TopicList);
```